# mgwt and gwt-phonegap project create and build without maven

Tags: gwt, cordova

How I can create and build a mgwt and gwt-phonegap eclipse project without maven? I see the wiki only it does the project creation and build using maven.

Regards,
Sandip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a normal gwt project
2. Download mgwt's jars
     https://code.google.com/p/mgwt/downloads/detail?name=mgwt-1.1.2-javadoc.jar&can=2&q=
3. Insert them in your gwt's project as normal jars
4. From your gwt.xml file inherit mgwt

   ```
   <extend-property name="user.agent" values="opera" />
   <inherits name="com.googlecode.mgwt.MGWT"/>
   ```
5. Happy coding

Comment: Thanks.. Actually Maven is fine.

Comment: I am able to create eclipse gwt project even without maven.

Answer (score 0):

JFYI, I found the following MGWT and GWT-Phonegap resource:

[Wrapping a MGWT Webapp with PhoneGap into a Native Android App](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/wrapping-mgwt-webapp-with-phonegap-into-a-native-android-app)

there's not one mention of Maven on that page ;-)